# How do I install CUDA from the extracted the local runfile?

Tags: software-installation, cuda

I've downloaded a runfile of a recent CUDA version (say, 12.0), made it executable, and ran it with:

```
./cuda_12.0.1_525.85.12_linux.run --extract=/tmp/cuda-install
```

and suppose I no longer have the original installer, just the extracted files.

I don't really see an installer in the extraction target die. What should I do? In older versions, I remember you could install things after extracting.

Comment: The instructions say to run the installer, not extract it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Why did Nvidia provide the `—extract` option if the  extracted files couldn’t be used? But yes, the OP should have kept the installer and run it.

Comment: @doneal24 That's a fine question for Nvidia but meanwhile I can think of few reasons for wanting to have individual files to manipulate.